# NGRX and service call on only the first load of component

Tags: angular, ngrx

Lets say I have a component called GridPageComponent.  this is one of many routes in my app.  I also have an action called LOAD_DATA that gets called in ngOnInit.  Is there a best practice for only making this call the 1st time the component is loaded?  I want to keep from make this service call if I navigate away and come back.  The only thing I could come up with is subscribing to the store and checking some flag to see if it has been loaded.  If it has not I would dispatch the action to fetch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. I would add some `loaded` property to your state and check that to see if the data is loaded already. If not, dispatch an action to load the data.

I would put this check in a canActivate guard though. This keeps the component code leaner. Your ngOnInit can be as simple as a select. The guard could also be reused across multiple routes that needed the data.

Comment: I am not sure if store details should be in canActivate guard. Can you provide some code samples?